# How to check ZMQ publisher is alive or not in c#

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I am using ZMQ NetMQ package in c# to receive the message from the subscriber. I am able to receive the msg but I am sticking in the while loop. I want to break the while loop if the publisher is stopped sending data.

Here is my subscriber code:

```
using (var subscriber = new SubscriberSocket())
            {
                subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4000");
                subscriber.Subscribe("A");

                while (true)
                {
                    var msg = subscriber.ReceiveFrameString();
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q :** *"How to check ZMQ publisher is alive or not in c# ?"*

**A :**
There are at least two ways to do so :

- a )
  modify the code on both the `PUB`-side and `SUB`-side, so that the Publisher sends both the `PUB/SUB`-channel messages, and independently of that also `PUSH/PULL`-keep-alive messages to prove to the `SUB`-side it is still alive, as being autonomously received as confirmations from the `PULL`-AccessPoint on the `SUB`-side loop. Not receiving such soft-keep-alive message for some time may trigger the `SUB`-side loop to become sure to `break`. The same principle may get served by a reversed `PUSH/PULL`-channel, where `SUB`-side, from time to time, asks the `PUB`-side, listening on the `PULL`-side, using asynchronously sent soft-request message to inject a soft-keep-alive message into the `PUB`-channel ( remember the TOPIC-filter is a plain ASCII-filtering from the left to the right of the message-payload, so `PUSH`-delivered message could as easily send the exact text to be looped-back via `PUB/SUB` back to the sender, matching the locally known TOPIC-filter maintained by the very same `SUB`-side entity )
- b )
  in cases, where you cannot modify the `PUB`-side code, we still can setup a time-based counter, after expiring which, without receiving a single message ( be it using a loop of a known multiple of precisely timed-`aSUB.poll( ... )`-s, which allows for a few, priority-ordered interleaved control-loops to be operated without uncontrolled mutual blocking, or by using a straight, non-blocking form of `aSUB.recv( zmq.NOBLOCK )` aligned within the loop with some busy-loop avoiding, CPU-relieving `sleep()`-s ). In case such timeout happens, having received no actual message so far, we can autonomously break the `SUB`-side loop, as requested above.

Q.E.D.